# Find values in 2D array (extremely large) in Python

Tags: python, indexing, parallel-processing

I have one list with four parameters (so 4 columns = x,y,value,id) and a matrix2D in which each element is a zip (x, y). I need to create a new 2D array containing value and ID, based on the matrix2D.

This is my code, but it takes too long because there are many "for"

```
njg, nig = 1427688,1427688
matrix2D = [[(x,y) for x in lon] for y in lat]

outland = np.zeros((njg, nig))
out_id = np.empty((njg, nig), dtype=object)

for x,y,values,id in list:
       for ix, row in enumerate(matrix2D):
           for iy, i in enumerate(row):
               if matrix2D[ix,iy]==(x,y):
                  out_value[ix,iy] += values                
                  out_id[ix,iy] = np.append(out_id[ix,iy],id)
```

I tried to parallelize it to decrease the time

```
def find_index(matrix2D,elem):
  # Find the nearest latitude and longitude
  x,y,values,id = elem 
  for ix, row in enumerate(matrix2D):
     for iy, i in enumerate(row):
        if matrix2D[ix,iy]==(x,y):
           yield ((ix,iy,values,id))
####
list_index = pool.starmap(find_values,[(matrix2D,elem) for elem in list])
for x,y,values,id in list_index:
       out_value[x,y] += values               
       out_id[x,y] =  np.append(out_id[x,y],id)
```

but a memory error appears

Any solution to decrease the search time between matrices? not necessarily parallelizing

Comment: what is matrix2D? if A numpy array you can just do matrix2d == (x, y)..

Comment: yes, matrix2D = [[(x,y) for x in lon] for y in lat]

Comment: but it is a list of list or numpy array?

Comment: What is `id`? What is `out_part`? Can you please provide a *minimal working example*?

Comment: to make it simpler, the list has 4 columns, which contains ID

Comment: and yes, matrix2D is a list of list @DaniMesejo